# Compare date varchar format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a few columns. One of the column is named flight_date is varchar format.

It has a date stored in it in format like '08/12/2015' which is mm/dd/yyyy

I want to run a query which will return me a list of the records with date in 2016.

Can someone help me out please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use  `SUBSTR` function for just cut last 4 character.

```
 SELECT * FROM yourtable where SUBSTR(flight_date, -4) = '2016'
```

Though, it is recommended to store date value in [appropriate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) type column and not in varchar.